# How do we pass the guest token to Iframe of superset

Tags: c#, angular, iframe, token, apache-superset

I'm exploring superset and working on integration of superset dashboard embedding. I have a working superset, with following changes :

`FEATURE_FLAGS = { "EMBEDDED_SUPERSET": True, "ENABLE_CORS" : true, "ENABLE_PROXY_FIX" : true }`

Created a user in Superset with PUBLIC and GAMMA user role. Have created a dashboard and added that dataset to permission of PUBLIC and GAMMA roles.

I'm able to generate Guest token, and pass it to EMBEDDED URL.

```
<iframe src="https://<superset-host-url>?token=<token>&next=/superset/dashboard/<dashboardId>?standalone=true" width="100%" height="750px">
```

However the  loads with Login page and redirects to the same page when I tried to enter credentials on the page.

[Redirects to same page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzgj5.png)

Note : We are using C# for backend and Angular for UI
Generating guest token : generate access token for user, get csrf token for access token, then added csrf token and access token for getting guest token API

How do I pass my generated GUEST TOKEN to IFRAME to embed Superset dashboard in our website.

Comment: Were you able to solve this Pavan ?

Answer (score 0):

The url for the iframe could look like:

```
  <iframe
      title="Dashboard"
      src="http://localhost:8088/login?token=1234abcd456/superset/dashboard/11?standalone=3"
      width="100%"
      height="800px"
      sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts"
    ></iframe>
```

Also are you handling the redirect inside the superset_config.py?
You can write a custom security manager.
Example snippet referred from: -

> https://www.tetranyde.com/blog/embedding-superset

```
if token == '1234abcd456':
            login_user(user, remember=False, force=True)
                return redirect("yourUrl")
```

Comment: Did this work for you Pavan?