# I am trying to embed individual charts of superset using iframe in my React App. Everytime I have to login to view the charts. How can I solve this?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, apache-superset

I actually want to make graphs available without login in view only mode using guest token. I tried sending guest token in the url in various ways, but none of it worked.

I tried sending guest token in the iframe URL as [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76226932/how-do-we-pass-the-guest-token-to-iframe-of-superset#:%7E:text=Created%20a%20user%20in%20Superset,pass%20it%20to%20EMBEDDED%20URL.)

But it didn't work.
What I basically want to achieve is any graph in this account (Account contains multiple dashboards and here I am referring to multiple graphs from any dashboard).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To embed a chart in your React App you need to use the following package: [@superset-ui/embedded-sdk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@superset-ui/embedded-sdk)

Don't forget to configure your `superset_config.py` enabling `CORS` and `GUEST_TOKEN` variables.